# How to change those MySQL codes to PDO ? and how to escape a string with pdo codes?

Tags: php

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_pass, user_email, user_date, user_level)
                VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'
                    , '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "'
                    , '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "'
                    , now(), 0)";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're having?  The PHP website has good documentation on how to achieve parametrized queries: http://ca3.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: The codes are working but because MySQL will be deprecated I wanted to change them them to PDO codes The problem is that I am not able to escape the strings with PDO codes so I need help if possible and thankyou

Comment: You should look into parametrized queries, you don't need to escape individual arguments yourself.

Comment: Also a good resource: http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-php-using-prepared-statements

Answer (score 1):

```
// configuration
$dbtype     = "sqlite";
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$user_name='Mohoni';
$user_pass='mohinipass';
$user_email='mohini@yopmail.com';
$user_date='2014-03-21';
$user_level='first';

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name,user_pass,user_email,user_date,user_level)     
VALUES (:user_name,:user_pass,:user_email,:user_date,:user_level)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':user_name'=>$user_name,
':user_pass'=>$user_pass,
':user_email'=>$user_email,
':user_date'=>$user_date,
':user_level'=>$user_level));
```

You can use `$conn->quote`  for string as follows :

```
$conn->quote($user_name);
```